# subir imagen con ajax y php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, imagen

en el siguiente script que he escrito, he tratado de subir una imagen y renombrarla con php pero no me funciona os dejo el código a ver si veis vosotros dónde me equivoco. Me  da el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\subirImagen.php on
>   line 10

y no se la verdad de dónde puede venir agradecería algún consejo o a haber si alguien ve el error. La verdad llevo todo el dia con esto y no soy capaz de encontrar el error pues me urge bastante. Gracias

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("click", "#anadir", function() { 
        var file_data = $('#afile').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('foto', file_data);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'imagenResultado.php', 
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: form_data ,                         
            processData:false,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
               $("#contenido").html(data);
              alert(file_data);    

            }
         });

        });






})
```

este es el archivo subirImagen.php

```php
<?php

 function getSubirNombrarImagen($imagen){

    $nombreTemporal = $imagen['foto']['tmp_name'];
    $cadena = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQVWXYZ1234567";
    $longitud = strlen($cadena);
    $archivo = $imagen['foto']['name'];
    $nombreFinal= "i";
    $extension = explode(".", $archivo);
    $ext = $extension[1]; //AQUI LA EXTENSION
    for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++){
        $aleatorio = rand(1, $longitud);
        $caracter = substr($cadena, $aleatorio, 1);
        $nombreFinal.= $caracter;
    }
    $nombreFinal.= ".";
    $nombreFinal.= $ext;
    move_uploaded_file($nombreTemporal, 'uploads/'.$nombreFinal);


    return $nombreFinal;


}
```

Y este es el archivo imagenResultado.php:

```php
    require_once("subirImagen.php");
    echo $resultado = getSubirNombrarImagen(@$_FILES['foto']);
```

Comment: El error hace referencia a que un indice de un arreglo no existe. El indice el parecer es el 1 lo que nos remite a la linea "$ext = $extension[1]; //AQUI LA EXTENSION". Antes de hacer esto verifica que $extension es un arreglo de dos posiciones al menos. O en su defecto que $archivo tenga el nombre del archivo junto con su extension

Comment: puedes cambiar `$ext = $extension[1];` por `$ext = strtolower(end($extension));` y esto solventara tu problema!

Comment: Si eso me libera del problema del error, que me da pero no me renombra bien la imagen y no me la sube al servidor. El script debe estar mal planteado pero no veo el error.

Answer (score 0):

Hola ya he dado con el fallo. Solo tenía que hacer unos cambios a mi código. Lo pongo a continuación por si a alguien le vale.

´´´ php
function getSubirNombrarImagen($imagen){

```
$nombreTemporal = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];/*he cambiado ésta línea y he cambiado también esta otra.*/
$cadena = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQVWXYZ1234567";
$longitud = strlen($cadena);
$archivo = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
$nombreFinal= "i";
$extension = explode(".", $archivo);
 $ext = strtolower(end($extension));
for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++){
    $aleatorio = rand(1, $longitud);
    $caracter = substr($cadena, $aleatorio, 1);
    $nombreFinal.= $caracter;
}
$nombreFinal.=".";
$nombreFinal.=$ext;
move_uploaded_file($nombreTemporal, 'uploads/'.$nombreFinal);


return $nombreFinal;
```

}
´´´

Se puede comparar los dos códigos y ver los resultados y el por qué no me funcionaba. He comentado las lineas que he cambiado.